# Is it possible set the JPEG quality using the get_serving_url() in Google App Engine?

Tags: image, google-app-engine

When using `get_serving_url(user.photoBlobKey)` to return an image URL from the GAE Blobstore, the Google Images API returns a JPEG image with quality = 70 and size = 512px as default.

Is there any way to increase the default JPEG quality returned by `get_serving_url()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not.

If you think it's a useful feature you can add an item to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), from there the team will assess the demand for implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

There's an undocumented URL parameter `l`, you can add it to the end of the image URL like so: `=l100` (or `=s640-l70` if you have another param before it) that should modify the output quality of the JPEG. Seems to be `=l1` to `=l100`.

See also: [List of all the App Engine images service get_serving_url() URI options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148567/list-of-all-the-app-engine-images-service-get-serving-url-uri-options)

Answer (score -1):

you can't control the output quality but by requesting

```
get_serving_url(user.photoBlobKey, size=0)
```

you will get the original size of the image up to 1600px height and width.

the returned url will be automatically postfixed with =s0 which you could add also before rendering the image in the template for example.